# Using a check constraint on a date

Tags: sql

I want to make sure that a person's Date of Birth must be less than the current date.
So I declared in a table:

```
    staff_dob SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL CHECK (GETDATE() < staff_dob)
```

But when I keep getting conflicts with the check constraint. How do I fix this? Do I need to formate GETDATE() into a proper format that I use? I'm unsure on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
drop table test

create table test
(staff_dob datetime check (staff_dob < getdate()))


--this insert will fail

insert test
(staff_dob)
values
('1/1/2013')

--this insert will succeed

insert test
(staff_dob)
values
('1/1/2011')
```

I think your check comparison was in the wrong direction.

Comment: Is it how the date input should be like? I've been trying 12-DEC-1988 for example and its not even working

Comment: This is the whole script:drop table test

create table test
(staff_dob datetime check (staff_dob < getdate()))


--this insert will fail
insert test
(staff_dob)
values
('1/1/2013')

--this insert will succeed
insert test
(staff_dob)
values
('1/1/2011')

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Creating and Modifying CHECK Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Staff](
        [staffid] [int] NULL,
        [dob] [date] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Staff]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Staff] CHECK  (([dob]<getdate()))
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Staff] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Staff]
    GO
```

hope this helps